# Unable to login with a freshly installed Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, system-installation, login

I recently assembled my computer (AMD TR 2920x, Gigabyte X399, Nvidia RTX 2070) and wanted to install the later Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. Made a bootable USB and the installation went through fine.

Upon reboot, I was trying to login for the first time. It would accept the password, flash me a blank screen and take me back to the login screen.

It seems that many people have reported this and I tried different tricks, but none worked for me. Going to a tty (ctrl + alt + F3), these are the things that I tried:

1. sudo rm -r ~/.local
2. mv ~/ICEauthority ~/ICEauthority.backup
3. mv ~/Xauthority ~/Xauthority.backup
4. sudo apt-get purge lightdm; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install lightdm; dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
5. Installed latest nvidia
       drivers - sudo apt-get install nvidia-430; sudo apt-get install
       xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
6. '#5 froze my machine, mouse & keyboard doesn't work!
7. And probably a few more that I don't remember.

In this process, I have restarted my machine several times.

Appreciate help from the community to understand what is going on. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this with:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Comment: Thanks for this one-liner, it has fixed the issue right after rebooting!